# Get out a mix from both tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can i get out from mysql ORDER BY date from two tables with limit 4 ? I want to get out a mix from both tables ORDER BY date >= DATE(NOW()).

```
tbl1 
id      place1    date1  
1   |  example | 2013-01-05
2   |  example | 2013-07-05
3   |  example | 2013-23-05

tbl2
id      place2    date2  
1   |  example | 2013-05-05
2   |  example | 2013-06-05
3   |  example | 2013-20-05
```

Comment: Please add expected output to your question. It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: do 2 querys and take the top 4 from each, put each of them into 1 array then sort the array and take the top 4. There is proberly a better way to do it but this is a way

Comment: the mix is called `JOIN` and `ORDER BY rand()` in database world

Comment: @Ejay: No, not necessarily `JOIN` and `ORDER BY rand()` is called a stupidity in the database world. Better search on that first and why to prevent it. The OP might just want to look for something called `UNION` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html . A `JOIN` is something different and only a cross-table-join would make sense here which is highly likely not what OP is looking for.

Comment: I want to get out 4 outputs  ORDER BY date from date1 and date2. So if date1  from tbl1 have 2013-01-05 and 2013-07-05, the date2 2013-05-05 from tbl2 come in between there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id, place1 place, date1 date
        FROM tbl1
       WHERE date1 > CURDATE()
      UNION
      SELECT id, place2 place, date2 date
        FROM tbl2
       WHERE date2 > CURDATE()) tbl12
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 4
```

Comment: I am getting this error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: You're right, I forgot the alias. Now it should be fine.